# SQL query select unique images from multiple tag_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table similar to the one below. And I want to bring back unique results where tag_id matches multiple items.
So if I want to find each `image_id` that has the `tag_id = 106 and 73` I would like it to bring back `image_id 12345714 and 12345712`.

I've tried doing

```
SELECT * 
FROM tag_relationship
WHERE tag_id
IN ( 106, 73 )
```

But this brings back

```
        id  image_id    tag_id
        61  12345706    73
        70  12345712    73
        72  12345712    106
        76  12345714    73
        77  12345714    106
```

I've also experimented with `GROUP BY`, but that doesn't seem to be quite right.

Sample of full table:
`image_id` can have the same number in different rows, but will have a different `tag_id`.

```
       id   image_id    tag_id
        1   12345679    63
        2   12345679    83
        3   12345680    74
        4   12345680    108
        5   12345680    75
        6   12345683    103
        7   12345682    87
        8   12345682    105
        9   12345682    74
        10  12345682    81
        11  12345683    79
        12  12345683    109
        13  12345689    111
        14  12345689    69
        15  12345690    104
        16  12345687    110
        17  12345687    69
        18  12345687    91
        19  12345687    93
        20  12345687    63
        21  12345692    69
        22  12345692    104
        23  12345692    80
        24  12345692    76
        25  12345693    74
        26  12345693    99
        27  12345693    96
        28  12345693    94
        29  12345691    63
        30  12345691    69
        31  12345697    92
        32  12345697    76
        33  12345698    74
        34  12345699    97
        35  12345698    94
        36  12345699    98
        37  12345698    81
        38  12345699    105
        39  12345697    91
        40  12345694    100
        41  12345694    101
        42  12345694    94
        43  12345694    74
        44  12345696    78
        45  12345696    95
        46  12345696    112
        47  12345701    113
        48  12345701    114
        49  12345700    94
        50  12345700    91
        51  12345700    90
        52  12345702    87
        53  12345702    115
        54  12345702    80
        55  12345702    74
        56  12345704    78
        57  12345705    83
        58  12345705    84
        59  12345704    63
        60  12345705    104
        61  12345706    73
        62  12345706    64
        63  12345706    86
        64  12345706    88
        65  12345706    89
        66  12345713    80
        67  12345713    115
        68  12345713    81
        69  12345717    63
        70  12345712    73
        71  12345717    64
        72  12345712    106
        73  12345717    79
        74  12345712    74
        75  12345709    76
        76  12345714    73
        77  12345714    106
        78  12345715    68
        79  12345716    116
        80  12345715    69
        81  12345716    71
```

Comment: Maybe, you need to specify your database? I mean MSSQL, MySQL PostgreSQL or something else.

Comment: sorry, mysql for anyone else that comes across this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   image_id 
FROM     tag_relationship
WHERE    tag_id IN ( 106, 73 )
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: With indexes I *think* the multiple JOIN approach and/or multiple EXISTS approach may be faster.  This, however, is simpler to generalise without having to change the query structure as you add more IDs to the list.

Comment: This works for my needs. Thank you very much to everyone for the help.

Comment: What does the line "HAVING COUNT(*) = 2" do?

Comment: @TommyAdey - `GROUP BY` aggregates many rows into a single row.  `HAVING` is like a `WHERE` but is applied after the `GROUP BY` instead of before it.  `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows that have been aggregated together.  So, it means `keep only the results which are made up of exactly 2 input rows`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT image_id 
FROM tag_relationship
WHERE tag_id
IN ( 106, 73 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I've tried this also and it brings back  image_id 12345706 which only has the tag_id of 73 but doesn't have tag_id 106

Answer (score 0):

It might be really stupid/simple, but I think this will work:

```
SELECT image_id
FROM tag_relationship
WHERE 
  tag_id = 106 AND tag_id = 73
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either. Didn't bring back any results. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @TonyAlan This query will return no rows because a row in the table cannot have `tag_id =106 and 73` simultaneously.

Comment: @Igor Oh wow, thanks, I just couldn't see what was wrong. Stupid idea of me, sorry!

Comment: don't be sorry. Only those make no mistakes who does and writes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.image_id 
FROM tag_relationship t1
     JOIN tag_relationship t2 ON t1.image_id=t2.image_id
WHERE t1.tag_id=106
      and t2.tag_id=73
```